# How to test ServiceStack Service using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, servicestack

I have a rest service that I have created with ServiceStack, using nHibernate as a way of getting the data from a SqlCe database. I've been trying to write some unit tests using nUnit and Moq - I have successfully mocked the nHibernate implementation to return null, invalid objects and so on - but my tests always throw a `NullReferenceException` when it calls the base class to set the HttpStatus etc.

```
public List <ParameterDto> Get (ParameterAll parameterAll)
    {
        List <ParameterDto> parameterResponseList = new List <ParameterDto> ();
        try
        {
            List <ParameterDomainObject> parameterDomainObjectList = _ParameterDao.getAllParameters ();
            foreach (ParameterDomainObject parameterDomainObject in parameterDomainObjectList)
            {
                parameterResponseList.Add (parameterDomainObject.ToDto ());
            }
        }
        catch (WebServiceException webEx)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.ErrorCode         " + webEx.ErrorCode);
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.ErrorMessage      " + webEx.ErrorMessage);
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.ResponseStatus    " + webEx.ResponseStatus);
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.StatusCode        " + webEx.StatusCode);
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.StatusDescription " + webEx.StatusDescription);
            Debug.WriteLine ("WebServiceException.ErrorCode         " + webEx.ErrorCode);
        }
        catch (DomainObjectNotFoundException domainObjectNotFoundException)
        {
            base.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            base.Response.AddHeader ("Reason",
                                     domainObjectNotFoundException.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Exception: " + exception.Message);
            base.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            base.Response.AddHeader ("Reason",
                                     exception.Message);
        }
        /* Always throws an exception here, or anywhere base.Response is called */
        base.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;
        base.Response.AddHeader ("Reason",
                                 Strings.ParameterRestResponse_Get_OK);
        return parameterResponseList;
    }
```

The service works fine when testing it with RestClient and Firefox, and when I comment out the `base.Response` code so I'm guessing I'm just not setting something up right in the unit tests maybe?

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Method_Get_AllParameters_Unsucessful ()
    {
        Mock <IRequestContext> mockedRequestContext = new Mock<IRequestContext>();
        mockedRequestContext.SetupGet(f => f.AbsoluteUri).Returns("http:/localhost:8080/parameters/all");

        Mock<IParameterDao> mockedParameterDao = new Mock<IParameterDao>();
        mockedParameterDao.Setup (returns => returns.getAllParameters ()).Returns (new List <ParameterDomainObject> ());
        Assert.IsNotNull (mockedParameterDao);

        ParameterRestService service = new ParameterRestService(mockedParameterDao.Object)
        {
            RequestContext = mockedRequestContext.Object
        };

        List <ParameterDto> parameterDtos = service.Get (new ParameterAll ());
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ServiceStack (yet) ...but what is the base class?

Comment: As far as I know (still learning it myself!) it's the Apphost.. I'm trying to run the Service without the AppHost, since I have no way of setting the Mock objects if I use the AppHost, well not that I know of anyways :)

Comment: Not that this is [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671493/unit-testing-servicestack-services-with-custom-serialization-deserialization?rq=1 ] a duplicate, but take a look and see if it helps any. It is dealing with nUnit and unit testing against `AppHost`.

Comment: However, this [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790695/unit-test-httprequest-headers-with-servicestack/14791657#14791657 ] might answer your question.

Comment: Ah right, I have used that as a starting point but the same problem happens, not sure what is going on but still have a feeling its something simple that just needs set!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just need to mock the Response property of the Service class. It's protected with no setter but you should be able to mock it doing something like...

```
    Mock<IRequestContext> mockedRequestContext = new Mock<IRequestContext>();
    Mock<IHttpResponse> mockedResponse = new Mock<IHttpResponse>();
    mockedRequestContext.SetupGet(f => f.AbsoluteUri).Returns("http:/localhost:8080/parameters/all");
    mockedRequestContext.Setup(f => f.Get<IHttpResponse>()).Returns(mockedResponse.Object);
```